# Programming-how to find the angle

Tags: trigonometry, computer-science, angle, python

I want to write a function in python that has as two arguments, the sine and the cosine of an angle and it returns the angle. Which formula do we use to calculate the angle knowing the sine and the cosine? If we could just use the inverse trigonometric functions we wouldn't have to define two arguments for the function. I don't have an idea how we can calculate the angle. Can you help please?

Comment: A couple of notes.  Since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ both have period $2\pi$, the angle can only be determined up to a multiple of $2\pi$.  Also not every pair of values can be realized as the sine and cosine of a common angle (even if those values are restricted to absolute values less than or equal to $1$).  One needs values that satisfy $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.  Then the signs of the values will tell you which quadrant of the first period that angle belongs to (both positive means 1st quadrant, etc.).  So using the inverse trigonometric functions makes sense.

Comment: So first we check if the given values satisfy the equation $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. Then we check in which quadrant we are. Then we calculate with the inverse function the angle, either with arcsin or with arccos. What step is next? How do we use the quadrant? @hardmath

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) & [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2).

Comment: So I understand that you are not able to use any inverse function, right?

Comment: Is there an other way rather than to use the inverse function? @AlexSp3

Comment: Use `math.atan2(s,c)` in Python.

Comment: I ask repeatedly for values using the condition while (sin**2+cos**2!=1). However, sin, cos have not exact values, so we have to take a condititon for approcimative values. But whata condition could be appropriate?

Comment: @jessietoms You can do `abs(sin(x)**2+cos(x)**2 - 1) < eps` where eps is the max error you allowed for doing the computation. Then you can use the taylor series that I put in the answer.

Comment: My answer is based on a different reading of the question: not that someone has said "don't use inverse functions," but rather than "inverse-sine doesn't give me what I want, because it only produces answers in a half-circle of values,  and same for inv-cos and inv-tan." So my answer (basically "use atan2") is meant to instruct on how others have solved this problem in the past, and codified the result within the standard math library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
math.atan2(c, s)
```

will produce the angle, where $c$ is the known cosine and $s$ is the known sine. The value produced will lie between $-\pi$ and $\pi$; if you want it to be between $-180$ degrees and $180$ degrees, use

```
math.atan2(c, s) * 180.0/math.pi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to use any inverse function, given the sine and the cosine of an angle, you can compute the tangent of the angle:

$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}$$

And then, compute the $\arctan$ using the power series:

$$\arctan{x} = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \frac{x^9}{9} - ...$$
or
$$\arctan{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

In python code it would be something like this:

```
def get_angle(sinx, cosx):
    tanx = sinx / cosx
    arctanx = 0
   
    # More iterations means more accuracy
    for n in range(0, 20):
        arctanx += ((-1)**n)*((tanx**(2*n+1)) / (2*n+1))

    return arctanx
```

Comment: Two things: The solution here is only correct modulo pi as $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$. Second: The break condition should depend on how much the value of arctanx changes, as the rate of convergence will decrease when $\tan(x)$ get’s large.

Answer (score 2):

If `math.atan2` (as mentioned in John's answer) isn't allowed, then you could use:

```
import cmath
    
def get_angle(sinx, cosx):
    return cmath.log(cosx + 1j * sinx).imag
```

This works because [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ is equivalent to $\log(\cos(x) + i \sin(x)) = ix$.

Your instructor may still consider it “an inverse function”, though.

Answer (score 1):

A non-“cheating” approach to use if the standard `math.atan2` is not allowed:

```
import math

def atan2(y, x):
    # Use symmetry to restrict the result range to [0, pi/4]
    if y < 0:
        return -atan2(-y, x)
    if x < 0:
        return math.pi - atan2(y, -x)
    if y > x:
        return math.pi / 2 - atan2(x, y)
    # Normalize to unit circle to give c = cos(theta), s = sin(theta)
    r = math.hypot(x, y)
    c = x / r
    s = y / r
    # Use the small-angle identity sin(theta) = theta when applicable.
    if s <= 2e-8:
        return s
    # Otherwise, use half-angle identity
    tan_half = s / (1 + c)
    return 2.0 * atan2(tan_half, 1)
```

Note that there are no calls to trig functions *nor* inverse trig functions.  Instead, the algorithm works by recursively bisecting the angle until [the small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) can be used.